How to retain the vehicle mappings apply constraint in Google OR-Tools?
here goes my first question in stack overflow.
I'm tasked with implementing a max stop constraints per vehicle in my VRP.
here is the issue that Im facing.

`"truckLevelConstraints": {
    "1251BOX1": {
      "maxStop": 4,
      "maxMileage": 500
    },
    "1251BOX2": {
      "maxStop": 5,
      "maxMileage": 500
    },
    "1251BOX3": {
      "maxStop": 6,
      "maxMileage": 500
    },
}`


so from the above json, you can see the mappings
now here is my below code
`long[] vehicleCapacities = (long[]) value;
      routingModel.addDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
          routingModel.registerUnaryTransitCallback((long fromIndex) -> 1),
          0,
          vehicleCapacities,
          true,
          RoutingDimensionConstants.MAX_STOP);`


the vehicleCapacities is a long[] which will contain the max stop, so in my case it will [4+1,5+1,6+1]
P.S - adding plus one for depot.
Now after I get the solution, the max stops constraints are applied but the truck mappings are lost.
We have 15 orders
the solution would look like this ->

1251BOX1->6 orders
1251BOX2 -> 4 orders
1251BOX3-> 5 orders


as u can see the mappings are lost, the trucks names are randomized.
is there anyway to fix this and keep the truck-mappings ?
I tried this code

`for (int i = 0; i < routingDimension.getVehicleCount(); i++) {
              RoutingDimension dime = routing.getDimensionOrDie(RoutingDimensionConstants.CAPACITY);
              dime.cumulVar(routing.start(i)).setMin(1L);
              dime.cumulVar(routing.end(i)).setMax(entryList.get(i).getValue().get("maxStop") + 1);
            }`



but this gives me an empty solution error.
Tried the above code using a for loop for iterating the vehicleCount and setting the min and max but didnt work.

can you check the constraint you are creating ? Reading a hash map iteratively will not get you a consistent order.

Hey, thanks for the reply, I did have a look at the dimension which I created. I don't see anything wrong here. Besides its a treemap so it already in sorted format so iterating it will give me a correct order
